# Set timeout for request to my server

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

1. I want that all requests to my server will get response in 2 seconds.
2. If my server have an issue (for example: it's turned off), the user will get an error response after 2 seconds.

The status now is that if there is an issue in my server, the user and browser, try for long time to connect. I don't want this.

Currently I am not using any load-balance or CDN.

Sometimes my server fall down. I don't want my users to wait forever for response, and hangout the browser.

I Think that load balance service OR CDN can help.

What I want it that after 2 seconds, the service before my server will return default error message.

Which service can handle it for me?
I checked out CloudFront and CloudFlare, and didn't found something like that.

More info:
1. Cache cannot help, because my server return different results for every request.
2. I cannot use async code.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure 2 second timeout in CloudFront, however you can configure it return some error page (which you might host anywhere outside of your server) if server is not responding properly.

Take a look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/custom-error-pages.html

Moreover, these error responses are cached (you can specify for how long they will be cached), so next users will get errors right away

Comment: The problem is that my server not respond with any error code.

Comment: Here is the quote from document I linked: "When a server error occurs, either your origin server returns an HTTP status code in the 500 range to CloudFront, or CloudFront doesn't get a response from your origin server for a certain period of time and assumes a 504 status code (gateway timeout)." Hope this helps